# checkbox checked after reloading pages and backing to previous page

Tags: php, checkbox

I need only which I checked! not all.

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION["design"])) { ?>
<input type="checkbox" onkeypress="isInputNumber(event)" name="design" value="<?php echo $design_id; ?>" checked>
<?php } else {?>
<input type="checkbox" onkeypress="isInputNumber(event)" name="design" value="<?php echo $design_id; ?>">
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: what do you want to do with it, and also clarify what did you try.

Comment: When someone mistakenly clicked on any checkbox and then click next, but he wants to solve his/her mistake and click on back button, the checkbox information will not be cleared. I want only which data user checked on the checkbox. Not all data.

Comment: @SiamAlMahmud your code look good but I don't understand what do you want to do with it, please share more information.

Comment: can i talk to you in hindi ?

Comment: yes you can talk in Hindi. btao kya krna chahte ho is code me?

Comment: checkbox main click karne ki badme maine next click karkar next page me giya. magar suddenly mera kheal aya ki maine wrong checkbox click kara. and then maine back click karke us page pe bawas giya jahape maine wrong checkbox ke click kiyatha. magar uhape koi checkbox checked nehi tha. main cahatahu ki wo checkbox me check page reloading ke badvi rehe. ye possible hay keya ?

Comment: ha aap ise session ke jariye manage kr skte hain.

Comment: magar keyse vai ? mujhe help karo.

Comment: aap code share kuchh or information, taki mai us par kuchh kr ke dekh saku.

Comment: main chahtahu ki if isset($_SESSION["design"]) == isset($design_id) ho to checkbox main check dekhayega. or nehi.

Comment: <?php if (isset($_SESSION["design"]) == isset($design_id)) { ?>
                                    <input type="checkbox" onkeypress="isInputNumber(event)" name="design" value="<?php echo $design_id; ?>" checked>
                                <?php } else {?>
                                    <input type="checkbox" onkeypress="isInputNumber(event)" name="design" value="<?php echo $design_id; ?>">
                                    <?php } ?>

Comment: aap `isset` galat use kar rhe hain bhai. mai answer niche likh rha hu.

Comment: pls mujhe batao main keya karu ye problem solve korneke liye. isset keya du ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working code, Please follow it to use `isset` method.

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION["design"]) && $_SESSION["design"] == $design_id) { ?>
<input type="checkbox" onkeypress="isInputNumber(event)" name="design" value="<?php echo $design_id; ?>" checked>
<?php } else {?>
<input type="checkbox" onkeypress="isInputNumber(event)" name="design" value="<?php echo $design_id; ?>">
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: sab feild ko checked dekha rahahe

Comment: verify that `$_SESSION["design"]` and `$design_id` has same values.

Comment: ha vai. same hain. magar kam kar nehi raha. sab checkbox main checked ho geya. main cahtahu ki ek main ho, jismain maine click kiya thaka. baki sab nehi

Comment: update kiya hai fir se check krna ak bar jo answer upar hai.

Comment: Thanks mere bhai. kam kiya